# The POM for <some_project> is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

**What I am doing?**

I have created a `maven` project, where I bundle some external jars

```
project/pom.xml
       /bin
           /safebrowsing2_2.11-0.2.5.jar
           /scala-http-client_2.11-1.0.jar
```

The libraries `safebrowsing2_2.11-0.2.5.jar` and `scala-http-client_2.11-1.0.jar` are bundled because they are not available in `Nexus` and are custom jars needed for legacy purposes.

`pom.xml` uses following `plugins` to bundle them up in one jar

```
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-jars</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/bin</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

When this build runs on `Jenkins` it fails with following warnings

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.shn:project-safebrowsing2_2.11-0.2.5.jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.shn:project-scala-http-client_2.11-1.0.jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

and error is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project-installer: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.project-installer:war:0.19.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.shn:project-external-dependencies-safebrowsing2_2.11-0.2.5.jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, com.shn:project-scala-http-client_2.11-1.0.jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.shn:project-safebrowsing2_2.11-0.2.5.jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in company (http://172.62.11.24:8080/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
16:17:03 [ERROR] 
16:17:03 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
16:17:03 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
16:17:03 [ERROR] 
16:17:03 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
16:17:03 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

**Question**

Yes, I know that they do not have `pom.xml`, but how do I let the build pass and generate artifact?

Comment: Some may find the correlation between the warning and the error somewhat interesting, others merely note the warning^^ In order to execute the goal you have to properly install the 2 erroneous artifacts.

Comment: Install them into your nexus and it's done. Or start using a repository manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`install-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) goal of [Maven's Install Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/):

> *... to install an externally created artifact into the local repository, along with its POM.*

Use the [`deploy-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) goal of [Maven's Deploy Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) to:

> *install the artifact in the remote repository.*

... rather than placing the artifacts in your project's directory.